# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null

Tags: openlayers-2, cesium

I am getting this error when i display "name" on the map from geojson for "point" entities.

```
var pointStyle = (function () {
  var style1 = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
      scale: 1,
      src: imgPath + 'location.png'
    }),
    text: new ol.style.Text({
      text: null,
      scale: 1,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: '#000000'
      }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: '#FFFF99',
        width: 3.5
      })              
    })
  });
  var styles = [style1];
  return function (feature, resolution) {          
    style1.getText().setText(feature.get("name"));
    return styles;
  };
})()
```

When i run my angular 2 application, map is rendered with point entities (some point entities with "name"). All the entities are not displayed with "name". And this is when i get this error.

When i zoom in , then all the point entities "name" is loaded. Then i don't get this error.

How to solve this ?

Comment: Try replacing `text: null` with `text: ''` and see if that works better.

Comment: Sorry, text: '' didn't work.

Comment: Did it give a different error?  Can you look through the stack trace and figure out where the error actually comes from?  I think we need more information.

Comment: Text is not required field. Try without `text: null`.